# Eclipse: code editor doesn't open

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having a problem in my eclipse where i can't open the code editor. I already tried to restart the eclipse several times and also restarted my PC but nothing changed.

Can someone help me or give me tips how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Goto -->
  Windows menu
  Reset Perspectives

Answer (score 0):

Right click on JAVA Perspective and click on Reset.
If it does not work, close the JAVA perspective then reopen it again.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse click on window on the top bar -> new new editor